# eql? override doesn't work in Hash

Tags: ruby

`Hash` checks its keys with `eql?`:

```
foo = 'str'
bar = 'str'

foo.equal?(bar)   #=> false
foo.eql?(bar)     #=> true

h = { foo => 1 }
h[foo]            #=> 1
h[bar]            #=> 1
```

But this doesn't work if I use my own class as a key:

```
class Cl
    attr_reader :a
    def initialize(a)
        @a = a
    end
    def eql?(obj)
        @a == obj.a
    end
end

foo = Cl.new(10)
bar = Cl.new(10)

foo.equal?(bar)   #=> false
foo.eql?(bar)     #=> true

h = { foo => 1 }
h[foo]            #=> 1
h[bar]            #=> nil
```

Why does the last line return `nil` instead of `1`?

Comment: `puts` always returns `nil`.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 I don't think you got the point.

Comment: @Bиталий Папроцький The question itself is good if you had stated it with care. A downvote may turn into an upvote if you read the comments here and format your question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eql?` must be used in conjunction with a `hash` method that returns a hash code:

```
class Cl
  attr_reader :a
  def initialize(a)
    @a = a
  end
  def eql?(obj)
    @a == obj.a
  end
  def hash
    @a
  end
end
```

See [this blog post](http://javieracero.com/blog/the-key-to-ruby-hashes-is-eql-hash).

Comment: The accompanying section from the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#class-Hash-label-Hash+Keys): *"Two objects refer to the same hash key when their `hash` value is identical and the two objects are `eql?` to each other. A user-defined class may be used as a hash key if the `hash` and `eql?` methods are overridden to provide meaningful behavior."*

Comment: BTW, `hash` should return a `Fixnum`